# Java - Not printing what I would like?

Tags: java

As a beginner and in java, I'm having some trouble with the output of my code. The code only prints the values of "a","b" and "c" for the value I put into running the code. How would I amend this for it to print all values up to and including the value I put into running the code
Could someone help please? Thank you!

```
class Numbers
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
    for ( int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
        {
        int a = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        System.out.print(a);
        int b = (a*a);  
        int c = (a*a*a);
        System.out.print(b);
        System.out.print(c);
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Could you clarify a bit?

Comment: Please give us some example input and output. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Do you want to specify the number of iterations by using an input parameter ?

Comment: When running the code if I use the number 3 for example, the code provides the numbers 3, 9 and 27. However, I'd like the code to provide the numbers 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 8 and 3, 9 and 27. In other words, I'd like the loop to apply to the prints as well, but it seems that the code is only printing the string length values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So did I get it right in your comment? You want to pass a number that tells you how many iterations the loop should run. And for any iteration you want to write a incrementing number, its square and its cube?

```
class Numbers {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        if (args.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("Please specify number.");
            return;
        }
        int iterationCount = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        for ( int i = 0; i < iterationCount; i++) {
            int a = i;
            System.out.print(a);
            int b = (a*a);  
            int c = (a*a*a);
            System.out.print(b);
            System.out.print(c);
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this makes sense!

Comment: Actually you could just make `i` and `a` the same variable. There is no point in having the same value in two variables. I'll keep the code in the answer as it is, just because it shows better how I got to this code from the initial question's code.

Answer (score 0):

The loop just runs once because your argument is 3.  So `args.length` is 1. And that is why 3, 9, and 27 are printed.

For the loop to run three times you might evaluate the `String` passed as `args[0]` as an `int`. In that case you need something like (no exception handling here):

```
int numLoops = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
for ( int i = 0; i < numLoops; i++)
        System.out.print(i);
        System.out.print(i*i);
        System.out.println(i*i*i);
}
```

Comment: How would I be able to change the args.length to be the same as the argument? I,e, the code in this case to provide the numbers 1,1,1,2,4,8,3,9,27

Comment: @Kavzaz1, the length of arguments is 1 because you only have one argument. If you want to have more argument then provide them (via command line).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
javac Numbers.java
java Numbers 1 2 3
```

This should work. In first iteration of your for loop, the a variable will be 1, so it will print 1, 1 and 1. In second iteration, your a variable will be 2, so it will print 2, 4 and 8 and in your third iteration, your a variable will be 3, so it will print 3, 9 and 27.

Comment: This will work however if i were to input the first 40 numbers for example that would be very tedious! So I'd prefer if the code did all the working on it's own?

Comment: Yes, I agree. Solution to your problem is for loop that loops from 1 to the num of parameter. So if i would type `java Numbers 40` the you need to say `for (int i = 1; i<=Integer.parseint(args[0]); i++) { //print(i), print(i^2), print(i^3) }`